# POST array data in php

Tags: php, post

I'm trying to post array data to another php, but it doesn't work..

here is my code below.

> in func.php

```
function search($x, $y)
{

  ...

  $martx = array();
  $marty = array();


  foreach($load_string->channel as $channel) {
    foreach($channel->item as $item) {
      array_push($martx, $item->mapx);
      array_push($marty, $item->mapy);

    }
  }

    echo"<form method=post action='map.php'>";
    for($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++)
    {
      //echo $martx[$i]."<br/>";
      //echo $marty[$i]."<br/>";
      echo "<input type='hidden' name='martx[]' value='".$martx[$i]."'>";
      echo "<input type='hidden' name='marty[]' value='".$marty[$i]."'>";
    }
    echo "</form>";

    header("location: map.php?x=$x&y=$y");
}
```

`martx` and `marty` have data from parsed xml `$load_string`

And I want to post these data to map.php by form with POST. So, I expect that I can use two arrays `martx` and `marty` in `map.php` like `$_POST[martx][0]`..

But when I run this code, page remains in func.php, instead of redirecting to map.php

Am I make some mistake?

Thanks in advance.

========================================================================

Thank you all for your kind concern and helpful advice!

I edit my code with your advice,

1. I delete all echo with using javascript
2. And I add submit code

here is my code below

```
....

$martx = array();
$marty = array();

foreach($load_string->channel as $channel) {
foreach($channel->item as $item) {
  array_push($martx, $item->mapx);
  array_push($marty, $item->mapy);

  }
}

?>
<form method='post' action='map.php?x=<?=$x?>&y=<?=$y?>' id='market'>
  <script language="javascript">
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
      document.write('<input type="hidden" name="martx[]" value="<?=$martx[i]?>">');
      document.write('<input type="hidden" name="marty[]" value="<?=$marty[i]?>">');
    }
    document.getElementById('market').submit();
    </script>
</form>
<?php
//header("location: map.php?x=$x&y=$y");
```

}

With this code, page redirect to `map.php` successfully.

But I can't get data like `$_POST['martx'][i]` in `map.php`

I think `document.write` line cause problem

when I write code like

```
document.write('<input type="hidden" name="martx[]" value="$martx[i]">');
```

result of `$_POST['martx'][i]` is "$martx[i]"

Is any error in this code?

I want to use POST method but if I can't post data with POST,

then I'll use session-method as @Amit Ray and @weigreen suggested.

thanks again for your concern.

Comment: does exit after your header work?

Comment: echo '<form method="post" action="map.php">';

Comment: I put echo line after header, It shows. still alive after header line.

Comment: After header redirect you should add exit; In short just tell me what exactly you are looking for. There may be another good way for that.

Comment: Did you try the proposal of @AmitRay and could you add to the question as suggested? Thanks.

Comment: You should know whether form will be submit(my answer shown below)

Comment: You don't post to a page with a redirect like that. You have to use `cURL` to do it.

Answer (score 0):

First, You try to use `header('location: xxx')` to **redirect** user to another page.

As the result, you are **not submitting** the form, so you won't get data like `$_POST[martx][0]` as you expect.

Maybe you should try using session.

Comment: Actually, the `header()` will be ignored because it's after he echoed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Answer (score 0):

I can see some errors that you are making when you are doing header redirect. There should be no output before you call header redirect but you are doing echo before redirect. 
use session to tackle this issue

```
function search($x, $y)
{

  ...

  $martx = array();
  $marty = array();


  foreach($load_string->channel as $channel) {
    foreach($channel->item as $item) {
      array_push($martx, $item->mapx);
      array_push($marty, $item->mapy);

    }
  }

 if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
 }
 $_SESSION["martx"] = $martx;
 $_SESSION["marty"] = $marty;
 header("location: map.php"); exit;
```

then in map.php you can retrieve the session variables

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();
 }
$martx = $_SESSION["martx"];
$marty = $_SESSION["marty"];
```

Then you can use a for loop  or foreach loop to iterate through the values